# cakephp check conditons when there is no validation

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, fetchall

How can I set up conditions to call mysql function from cakephp when there is no cakephp (from model) validation

code which call mysql function from controller :

```
$generateDocNum = $data_source->fetchAll("
select generateDocNum(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) as generateSn
", array(
'MNF',
$codeTelpArea, // city
$this->request->data['Manifest']['date'], // date
$codeBranch, //branch
$codeModa //Moda
));
```

The code running well, but the problem is that when the validation returns false (ex : notEmpty validation), the function has already been called. I just want to call that function when the validation is finished.

I have tried using

```
$this->Model->validationErrors
```

and

```
$this->Model->invalidFields()
```

but this isn't working at all.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried calling function between

```
if ($this->Model->save()){
 //calling mysql function here
}
```

Comment: yes, I has already been tried using between it, but I need to set my field from return of mysql function which I've called